# Switch back to path when resume job from background

Tags: bash, zsh, directory, background-process, cd-command

Say I open `~/vim.txt`, push that to background, then `cd` to another path. When I bring that job to foreground, is there an option to switch back to old path? I noticed it says `pwd`, so I assume it is possible.

Comment: Are you opening the file in vim? If so, a tag for vim to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible in zsh, and in fact it's easy thanks to the direct access to the job parameters provided by the [zsh/parameter module](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html). You can use a job number or any job specification (`%+`, `%-`, `%foo`, etc.) as a subscript in the array.

```
zmodload zsh/parameter
fgcd () {
  local dir=$jobdirs[${1:-%+}]
  # If the jobspec matched, then call cd. Otherwise it's probably a bad
  # job spec, but call fg anyway to get the usual error message.
  if [[ -n $dir ]]; then cd $dir; fi
  fg $1
}
```

Bash also keeps track of the information, but I don't think it's exposed. On some systems, you can obtain the current working directory of the job's process, and switch to it. For example, on Linux, `/proc/$pid/cwd` is a symbolic link to that process's working directory.

```
fgcd () { # Linux only
  local pid=$(jobs -p $1)
  if [[ -n $pid ]]; then cd /proc/$pid/cwd; fi
  fg $1
}
```

Since it can also be useful, here's a zsh version. Unlike the function above, which switches to the job's original directory, this one switches to the current working directory of the job's process leader.

```
fgcd () { # Linux only
  local pid=${${${jobstates[${1:-%+}]}#*:*:}%\=*}
  if [[ -n $pid ]]; then cd /proc/$pid/cwd; fi
  fg $1
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: This works great, but unfortunately when I accidentally switch to non-existent job it switches from current dir to `~/`. Any suggestions? I'm using the first answer btw.

Comment: @Senthil: In that case the job data was empty so `cd` was called with no argument (which means `cd` to your home directory). I've added a test in my answer. Tip: after calling `cd`, you can call `cd -` to go back to the directory you just left.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks Gilles! (Thanks for `cd -` too).